# Changing the height of a cell in Grid View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Is it possible to edit the size of number of cells in a Grid View to match the height of another cell
For easier understanding to my question suppose the Grid View is a 2D array called mainView[n][2] where n is the number of objects in my ArrayAdapter
I need the cells from mainView[0][0] to mainView[4][0] to be the same height as mainView[1][0] which contains a gallery or some photos
Could this be done programmatically? if not, what is the appropriate solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.RowStyle.Height = ....dp;
```

Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: that's for the whole row wright? Or you mean I should use 2 grid layouts together?

Comment: if you want to change your height of cell, you can resize it like that. But you can also make GridView's height as wrap_content which takes your photos height.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

In getView(), setting LayoutParams to specific position of convertView will solve your needs.

```
if(position>5&&position<11){
            android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams lp=new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(150*3, 250*3);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

}

Remember it affects an entire row. And don't forget too that position(e.g., 5, 11) would be used again. So you need other criteria.

It has been worked on my grid view(n*2)

Comment: could you please explain for me a little bit more, because i'm still a beginner and I couldn't find anything about this method in the documentation. What does the arguments of this method represent?
Also there is a return statement in the method, should I remove it or leave it as it is?

Comment: When you use a Gridview, you have to set an adapter.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html  All you need is in this link. Check it out.